# How can I install Ubuntu on a Macbook without affecting my existing OS X installation?

Tags: installation, macbook

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on MacBook? If so, how can I modify my partitions without affecting my existing Mac OS X installation?

Answer (score 1):

I made it last week. First install refit on mac. Tried so many times with partitioning tool in disk utility but gave an error and asked more reduce.

Anyway, due to defrag problems I gave up to continue with disk utility and I made a boot cd burning in disc utility with gparted (OS not gparted software which is in ubuntu repo) on it. Booted Gparted and made partition with it. After installing ubuntu 10.10 on this partition everythings worked fine, maybe I was lucky. But do not forget to make a full back up.

Now everthing works fine in leopard 10.6 and in ubuntu ...

Comment: Yes, reFit is a vital part of the picture here, since you'll need EFI support to get the partitioning working and be able to swithc between OSes at boot

Answer (score 1):

You don't need refit and any special hack...

Just start bootcamp and insert ubuntu cd instead of the windows one...

When you are in the ubuntu installer, choose manual partitioning and delete the bootcamp partition(created by your mac automatically) and use the free space for a new partition (ext4 mountpoint is '/')

If anything goes wrong you can delete the ubuntu partition from your mac. Note that mac uses efi so you don't have to worry about mbr stuff... Just don't erase the wrong partition (Mac OS X uses HFS+, )

Answer (score 0):

I believe the partitioning process would be similar to what you do using bootcamp for windows.

A lot of good info is available at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro

Answer (score 0):

Since Oneiric (11.10) and maybe before, the Ubuntu installation has an automatic install choice of "install alongside OS X".  I did not have to set up any partitioning beforehand, as suggested by the now many outdated webpages, including the official [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation).  However, as suggested there, I did install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) beforehand, to make sure nothing would go wrong.